# Why is foreign_key ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

I have 2 models with `has_one` and `has_many` associations.

**realm.rb**

```
class Realm < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :realm_type, foreign_key: "id"
end
```

**realm_type.rb**

```
class RealmType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :realms, foreign_key: "realm_type_id"
end
```

But when i preforming sql request `Realm.find(1).realm_type` in `rails console`, i get

```
Realm Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "realms".* FROM "realms" WHERE "realms"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
RealmType Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "realm_types".* FROM "realm_types" WHERE "realm_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

As you see, it ignores `foreign_key: "realm_type_id"` for `has_many` association in **realm_type.rb**

**UPD 1:**
Replaced `has_many` with `belongs_to`, still get the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `belongs_to`?

```
class RealmType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :realms, foreign_key: "realm_type_id"
end

class Realm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :realm_type
end
```